# How to restrict my website to IE8 and higher versions only

Tags: html

My website should only work for IE8 and higher versions .
How can I restrict the use of version change using developer tools to the users? 
 Is there a way to restrict that using Jquery?

This is my javascript to find out the browser mode and document mode of the user agent,but I don't restrict the user change the browser and document modes to IE7.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
* Author: Rob Reid
* CreateDate: 20-Mar-09
* Description: Little helper function to return details about IE 8 and its various compatibility settings either use as it is
* or incorporate into a browser object. Remember browser sniffing is not the best way to detect user-settings as spoofing is
* very common so use with caution.
*/
$(function(){
var browserInfo = IEVersion();
console.log($('meta'));
  alert(browserInfo.DocMode);
  $('meta').attr('rel','IE=7');
});
function IEVersion()
{
    var _n = navigator, _w = window, _d = document;
    var version = "NA";
    var na = _n.userAgent;
    var ieDocMode = "NA";
    var ie8BrowserMode = "NA";
    // Look for msie and make sure its not opera in disguise
    if (/msie/i.test(na) && (!_w.opera))
    {
        // also check for spoofers by checking known IE objects
        if (_w.attachEvent && _w.ActiveXObject)
        {
            // Get version displayed in UA although if its IE 8 running in 7 or compat mode it will appear as 7
            version = (na.match(/.+ie\s([\d.]+)/i) || [])[1];
            // Its IE 8 pretending to be IE 7 or in compat mode              
            if (parseInt(version) == 7)
            {
                // documentMode is only supported in IE 8 so we know if its here its really IE 8
                if (_d.documentMode)
                {
                    version = 8; //reset? change if you need to
                    // IE in Compat mode will mention Trident in the useragent
                    if (/trident\/\d/i.test(na))
                    {
                        ie8BrowserMode = "Compat Mode";
                        // if it doesn't then its running in IE 7 mode
                    } else
                    {
                        ie8BrowserMode = "IE 7 Mode";
                    }
                }
            } else if (parseInt(version) == 8)
            {
                // IE 8 will always have documentMode available
                if (_d.documentMode) { ie8BrowserMode = "IE 8 Mode"; }
            }
            // If we are in IE 8 (any mode) or previous versions of IE we check for the documentMode or compatMode for pre 8 versions                         
            ieDocMode = (_d.documentMode) ? _d.documentMode : (_d.compatMode && _d.compatMode == "CSS1Compat") ? 7 : 5; //default to quirks mode IE5                                                                      
        }
    }

    return {
        "UserAgent": na,
        "Version": version,
        "BrowserMode": ie8BrowserMode,
        "DocMode": ieDocMode
    }
}

function DisplayInfo()
{
    var browserInfo = IEVersion();
    alert('UserAgent: ' + browserInfo.UserAgent + '\nVersion: ' + browserInfo.Version + '\nBrowserMode: ' + browserInfo.BrowserMode + '\nDocMode: ' + browserInfo.DocMode);
}
```

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, why not use something like jquery.browser plugin?

Comment: You can't, just put a message in a very visible place saying "This is only intended to be viewed with ie8 or higher", anything you attempt can be bypassed

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, why not use something like jquery.browser plugin

Answer (score 1):

Try not to as this will annoy many possible users and force them to a competitors website.

Admittedly you might not be able to do much about the browser of choice if you are using an ActiveX control for instance.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph alone. Users can still use a partially broken site. They can't use a splash page telling them to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Conditional comments like thus:

```
 <!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

You can find more about this [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Answer (score 0):

> *how to restrict that using jquery*

Just not possible. Doesn't matter if it is good practice or bad. You just can't change browser settings thru jQuery or Javascript for that matter.

> *When ever the user is trying to change the version using developer tools*

I think what you can do is use this meta tag as the first one inside head :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This will force the IE out of compatibility mode and use the latest version, whatever it is.

When you use a server-side framework like ASP.Net, you cannot be sure that this will remain as the first tag inside head. So, for example in ASP.Net you can write this in the PreInit:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=Edge")
```

Alternatively, you can also push the header from the web server e.g. IIS.